Upstairs A/C unit only pushing air to one side of house
a few years back my upstairs HVAC unit was replaced.  The installer said the existing plenum from the previous unit was not large enough to create the needed volume.  He enlarged the plenum from the blower which has two  primary feeds/ducts 10" running to their respective splits.  The ducts are on the top of the plenum. The duct furthest from the blower gets all the airflow with only minimal airflow coming from the one closer to the blower.  I don't understand the physics. Had an AC guy come by, said the ducts need to come out the side of the plenum rather than the top and that was the reason for poor airflow to one side of the upstairs. When the unit comes on, the duct furthest from the blower is shaking with airflow and spins the blades on the ceiling fans on one side of the house and virtually none on the other.  Is this a real "thing" that having the two ducts exit the side of the plenum versus the top will make a difference.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  

make sure they didn't add a damper (that is now shut) on the one not getting flow.  A proper plenum will not have a problem with duct placement because the definition of a plenum is a space with equal pressure in it.

assuming all the flow is going into one line (at least 80+%, can i put a damper on that line and force more air thru the other?  I'd rather not redesign the plenum but am a newbi to this.

yes, it is typical to have dampers installed at plenums for exactly this reason.

First question is if it ever blew air evenly (even before the AC replacement a few years ago).  I'd start by disconnecting the one without good airflow from the plenum (or if you can open up the plenum itself), and make sure it has a full opening leaving the plenum.  Also check inside the plenum for obstructions or blockages for the duct with issues.  if that's all clear, then you'll need to start tracing that duct and find the obstruction somewhere down the line, whether it got crushed, has blocking debris in it somewhere, or something else.  If access is difficult, you may want to get an inexpensive endoscope that fits on a smartphone and run that down the duct where you can't see visually.
Also check to make sure that all of your vents on that duct are fully open, and that you have good return air from that area back to your AC unit as well.

The take-offs from the plenum should either be arranged symmetrically around it or use a purposely designed tee.
Or, if they are side-by-side like this, they should be far enough from the blower that their relative distance and position doesn't matter.  In other words you need a "long thin plenum" -- not a big box but a duct, 14 or 16 inches and at maybe 6 feet or more long.  Then you can tap two ducts into it side by side like this.     I don't know the calculations, these numbers are guesstimates.
Often the blower instructions include guidelines --- do you have the instructions?  You should have them if you just bought it.

These are installed incorrectly.
The blower in the AC unit will push the air in to the plenum in a given direction based on how it is installed (usually the 'top'). Typically you do not install any ducts on the top of the plenum, instead installing all duct takeoffs on the other sides at least 18 inches away from the top. This will result in roughly equal pressures delivered to all of the ducting.
Once the ducts are properly installed on the sides of the plenum, you should see balanced airflow. Either get the original contractor to correct this, or get someone who actually knows what they are doing to fix it.

would it be possible for me to add a damper to the duct with all the airflow to divert more to the other duct, without redesigning the plenum?

Yes, though it might make a lot of noise or still not lead to balanced flow.
